# Gson ignore too many properties in nested object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON with this structure:

```json
{
  "firstProperty": true,
  "thisIsAString": "hi",
  "myList": [
    {"myBool": true},
    {"myBool": false, "otherfield": true}
  ]
}
```

The `myList` is a `List<MyClass>` in the target class.
This `MyClass` only has the `myBool` field which causes the first element of the array to properly deserialize but unfortunately deserializing the second element causes it to fail with the error message `Unknown property 'myBool' for class my.package.MyClass at JSON path $.otherfield`.

Is there any way to just ignore fields in the JSON that don't exist in the target class of the deserialization? Maybe it is because of nested objects?

I already tried to add a custom type adapter like seen [here](https://www.examplefiles.net/cs/1263371) but it didn't even call the method (the target class is a record which is why i have to use the third party library `com.github.Marcono1234:gson-record-type-adapter-factory` to deserialize it)

Comment: Could you please provide the exact code you are using to create the `Gson` instance?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m5chbZN5

Comment: @Marcono1234 found the issue, I had to use the builder and turn on the allowUnknownProperties option...
Should've looked into those options before trying to fix it by testing random stuff 
Thanks for the amazing library!

Comment: Thanks, it is really great to see that my library is useful for you! I am considering changing the behavior to allow unknown properties by default. If you want you can describe your use case a bit more in detail in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Marcono1234/gson-record-type-adapter-factory/issues/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the third party library I use to deserialize into records has a TypeAdapterFactory which has a option to ignore unknown properties which is set to false per default.

Turning this option on produces the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `Gson` will ignore unknown fields automatically while deserialization. So, I assume that you have already created these 2 classes which look like:

```java
public class MyClass {
    private Boolean myBool;

    // getter, setter and toString
}

public class MyResult {
    private Boolean firstProperty;
    private String thisIsAString;
    List<MyClass> myList;

    // getter, setter and toString
}
```

Then you can serialize your JSON string as follows:

```java
String yourJsonStr = "" +
                "{\n" +
                "  \"firstProperty\": true,\n" +
                "  \"thisIsAString\": \"hi\",\n" +
                "  \"myList\": [\n" +
                "    {\"myBool\": true},\n" +
                "    {\"myBool\": false, \"otherfield\": true}\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
MyResult myResult = gson.fromJson(yourJsonStr, MyResult.class);
System.out.println(myResult.toString());
```

Console output:

> MyResult{firstProperty=true, thisIsAString='hi', myList=[MyClass{myBool=true}, MyClass{myBool=false}]}

Comment: That's roughly what I use.
What's the JSON that you used?

Comment: @Jakob Just same as you posted. I updated my code snippet to add the part of JSON string. BTW, the version of `Gson` I used is *2.8.9*.

Comment: I just made a new project and found out that the issue is related to the records. I use a third party library to deserialize into records (gson can't do that out of the box) and when doing so it'll spit out the error message. I'll try to debug the issue of the third party library and possibly be able to make a fork and fix it there

Comment: Nvm, there's a option in the builder of the TypeAdapterFactory where you can enable unknown properties, I did that and it now works like a charm, thank you for your help!